# Python datetime objects fail to match

Tags: python

I have 2 date time objects:

```
dt1 = 2016-04-18 20:15:07
dt2 = 2016-04-18 20:15:07+00:00
```

and I want to compare these 2 which should give me true as both are technically same. but when I do :

```
if(dt1 == dt2):
    print("times match!)
```

I always get a false condition here. Any pointers on how to get over this?

Comment: Your first snippet is not Python. What are `dt1` and `dt2` exactly?

Comment: You need to parse string and compare `DateTime` objects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python

Comment: No its not python. That's just a representation of the date time object value I have in python. The actual datetime object is getting created via an automation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `dt1` and `dt2` are string

```
import datetime

dt1 = "2016-04-18 20:15:07"
dt2 = "2016-04-18 20:15:07+00:00"


d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f:00")

print(d1)
print(d2)

if d1 == d2:
    print("times match!")
```